# Composer don't install sub depencencies

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a problem with composer.json.

Why my second composer.json don't install dependancies `fineuploader/php-traditional-server` when I execute composer `install` from **Project** ?

**Project > composer.json :**

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        ...
        "gaylordp/symfony-fineuploader-bundle": "dev-master"
        ...
```

**gaylordp/symfony-fineuploader-bundle > composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "gaylordp/symfony-fineuploader-bundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "require": {
        ...
        "fineuploader/php-traditional-server": "^1.2"
        ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you're pointing to the right version of `symfony-fineuploader-bundle`? I don't see any error here.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It' my dev bundle

Comment: did you use `composer require gaylordp/symfony-fineuploader-bundle` when adding the vendor ? `composer install` prioritize `composer.lock` over `composer.json` (so it doesn't have to resolve versions). If you have a `composer.lock` file and the vendor is not in it, it wont being installed during `composer install`